# how to do fake oidc auth during debug

Tags: .net, authentication, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

im building some blazor wasm project
i use company oidc
so in wasm i have

```
 builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(opt =>
{
  opt.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://xx.zz.pl/auth/cp";
  opt.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "xxx";
  opt.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
  opt.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
});
```

and i have api configured to use this

```
 builder.Services
   .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
   .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
   {
      options.Authority = "https://xx.zz.pl/auth/cp";;
   });
```

and this works fine but question is **how to skip this logon part during debug** so i do not have everytime i run login with my corp account

i can do on api part do that if debug then allow anonym and this will work fine for every request

but how in this frontend `webassembly` to hardcode some 'superadmin' account with all perms so it use this always during debug ? like fake oidc?

thanks and regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i did eventually in webassembly

```
if (builder.HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) 
{
   builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
   DebugAuthStateProvicer>();
}
else 
 builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication......
```

and this provider like

```
  public class DebugAuthStateProvicer : AuthenticationStateProvider
  {
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "DebugAdmin") };

            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Server authentication");
    }
   
    return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create your own local ClaimsPrincipal user, then I have used this code in my Startup.cs class (the request pipeline) to create a /login and /logout endpoint:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/login", async context =>
    {
        var claims = new Claim[]
        {
                            //Standard claims
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Joe Svensson"),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "Sweden"),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "joe@edument.se"),

                            //Custom claims
                            new Claim("JobTitle", "Developer"),
                            new Claim("JobLevel", "Senior"),
        };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims: claims,
                                          authenticationType: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity: identity);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        };

        //Sign-in the user
        await context.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user, authProperties);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<!DOCTYPE html><body>");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>Logged in!</h1>");
    });

    endpoints.MapGet("/logout", async context =>
    {
        //Do add a call to the signout method here
        await context.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<!DOCTYPE html><body>");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>Logged out</h1>");
    });
```

I hope it can of some inspiration for you.

Comment: Do You use it in blazor wasm project? or on blazor server side?

Comment: My code above was used in a classic ASP.NET core application. But I think it could work either way in blazor, the core is the SignInAsync part. You could put it in a App.Use() block if you want every request to have a valid user"?

Comment: it could in blazor serverside i belive  but webassembly is totaly diferent